# Why $\{0\}$ is linearly dependent?

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the case $x\in V, x\not=0_v$, then $S=\{x\}$ is linearly independent. I read this as *"In the set S, only x itself can express x."*. Ok, fine, it's by my intuition. But then I think about $\{0\}$, by definition it's linearly dependent. For me it's unfair since "$0$ itself can express itself" means "someone else can also express $0$".

It seems like the definition for the case of $0$ should be defined, but luckily in this definition of linearly dependent just fits, so we don't have to.

Why $\{0\}$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: `I read this as ...` Better use the definition. `Why {0} is linearly dependent?` Because if $v \in \{ 0 \}$ then $\lambda v = 0$ does *not* imply $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @dxiv: Yea I know. Why roses are red? Because we define those red flowers "rose".

Comment: @Niing Roses aside ;-) point was that your reading of what "*linearly independent*" means is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the first line of the [Wikipedia page on linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence):

> [...A] set of vectors is said to be **linearly dependent** if one of the vectors in the set can be defined as a linear combination of the others[.]

$\{0\}$ is a linearly dependent set. $0$ can be written as a linear combination of the other vectors in the set. Namely, the empty linear combination. [$$\sum_{v\in\varnothing}k_v v = 0.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)

Answer (score 1):

Talking about intuition: a good geometric intuition, at least for finite-dimensional vector spaces, is to say that a set of vectors is linearly independent iff the number of the vectors equals the dimension of their span.

As $\{0\}$ contains one vector but the dimension of its  span is zero, $\{0\}$ is linearly dependent.